# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor del botón pulsado?

Tags: javascript

Mi programa no imprime nada en `"pago"` y en `"formadePago"`, **siempre imprime lo mismo independiente del boton presionado**, entonces ***cual es el error***?

Deseo que imprima la forma de `pago`, correspondiente al **boton** presionado y que en `'pago'` sea el mismo valor que en `'formaDePago'`

---

### Las diferencias entre el primer y segundo intento son el código de Pasajero.prototype ,y que en la segunda añadí un Onclick a los botones

---

---

### Primer intento:

---

```js
// ** Usando constructor **

function Pasajero(identificador, nombre, email, celular, edad) {
  
  this.identificador = identificador;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.email = email;
  this.celular = celular;
  this.edad = edad;
  
  }

// Variables globales

var efectivo = document.getElementById('efectivo');
var cheque = document.getElementById('cheque');
var tarjeta = document.getElementById('tarjeta');
var evento = document.getElementById('crear');
var pasajeros = []; // Cantidad de pasajeros .length
var persona = "";
var t = "";


// ** Fin Constructor **
  
// ** Prototipo del constructor **

Pasajero.prototype = {
  
  pago: "",
  
  formaDePago: function() {
    
    if (efectivo) {
      return this.pago = 'efectivo';
    }
    else if(cheque){
       return this.pago = 'cheque';
    }
    else if(tarjeta){
       return this.pago = 'tarjeta';
    }
    else {
      console.log("Selecciona método de pago por favor");
    }
    console.log(pago);
    
  }
  
};


// Añadimos un evento con una función anónima..
evento.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  persona = new Pasajero((pasajeros.length + 1), "aena", "aena@gmail.com", "+56958274822", "24" );
  pasajeros.push((pasajeros.length + 1));
// Recorremos el array
pasajeros.forEach(function(e){console.log(e);});

// Recorremos el objeto creado del constructor
for (var i in persona) {
  
  document.write('<hr></hr>' + i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function' ? persona[i]() : persona[i]));
 
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="array">
    <input type="button" id="efectivo" value="Efectivo"/>
  <input type="button" id="cheque" value="Cheque"/>
  <input type="button" id="tarjeta" value="Tarjeta"/>
  <hr></hr>
  <input type="button" id="crear" value="Crear Pasajero"/>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Segundo intento:

---

```js
// ** Usando constructor **

function Pasajero(identificador, nombre, email, celular, edad) {
  
  this.identificador = identificador;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.email = email;
  this.celular = celular;
  this.edad = edad;
  
  }

// Variables globales

var efectivo = document.getElementById('efectivo');
var cheque = document.getElementById('cheque');
var tarjeta = document.getElementById('tarjeta');
var evento = document.getElementById('crear');
var pasajeros = []; // Cantidad de pasajeros .length
var persona = "";
var t = "";


// ** Fin Constructor **
  
// ** Prototipo del constructor **

Pasajero.prototype = {
  
  pago: "",
  
  formaDePago: function(t) {
    
    switch(t) {
        
      case 'efectivo': 
        
        return this.pago = 'efectivo';
        
        break;
       
      case 'cheque':
        
        return this.pago = 'cheque';
        
        break;
        
      case 'tarjeta':
        return this.pago = 'tarjeta';
        break;
        
      default: this.pago = 'Selecciona tu forma de pagar';
        
    }
   
}
};


// Añadimos un evento con una función anónima..
evento.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  persona = new Pasajero((pasajeros.length + 1), "aena", "aena@gmail.com", "+56958274822", "24" );
  pasajeros.push((pasajeros.length + 1));
// Recorremos el array
pasajeros.forEach(function(e){console.log(e);});

// Recorremos el objeto creado del constructor
for (var i in persona) {
  
  document.write('<hr></hr>' + i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function' ? persona[i]() : persona[i]));
 
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="array">
    <input type="button" id="efectivo" onclick="persona.formaDePago('efectivo')"value="Efectivo"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="persona.formaDePago('cheque')"id="cheque" value="Cheque"/>
  <input type="button" id="tarjeta" onclick="persona.formaDePago('tarjeta')"value="Tarjeta"/>
  <hr></hr>
  <input type="button" id="crear" value="Crear Pasajero"/>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma de pago la constituyes de la siguiente manera:

```
if (efectivo) {
   return this.pago = 'efectivo';
}else if(cheque){
   return this.pago = 'cheque';
}else if(tarjeta){
   return this.pago = 'tarjeta';
}else {
   console.log("Selecciona método de pago por favor");
}
```

Y si te fijas la variable efectivo siempre va a existir, ya que siempre va a existir el botón. Es por eso por lo que te está entrando en la primera condición y está obviando todas las demás, porque la referencia al botón siempre va a estar definida (en este caso en concreto tienes tu botón directamente en el HTML) y no detectas el evento cuando haces click en cada uno de los botones.

Lo que podrías hacer es detectar que botón se ha pulsado de la siguiente manera:

- Les pones una clase a todos los botones.
- Haces un manejador(handler) para detectar cuando los botones con esa clase han sido clickados.
- Mediante la palabra reservada `this` haces referencia al elemento que acabas de pulsar y obtienes su id.
- Mediante el id recuperado en el paso anterior puedes añadir el método de pago correspondiente haciendo un `switch` (en este caso muestro un mensaje en consola de cual se ha pulsado para que se pueda ver el funcionamiento).

Ejemplo:

```js
var botones = document.getElementsByClassName("boton");

for(var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
    botones[i].addEventListener('click', comprueba, false);
}

function comprueba(){
  switch(this.id){
    case "efectivo":
       console.log("hemos pulsado en efectivo");
       break;
    case "cheque":
       console.log("hemos pulsado en cheque");
       break;
    case "tarjeta":
       console.log("hemos pulsado en tarjeta");
       break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="efectivo" value="Efectivo" class="boton"/>
<input type="button" id="cheque" value="Cheque" class="boton"/>
<input type="button" id="tarjeta" value="Tarjeta" class="boton"/>
```

Comment: Sin mencionar que a la propiedad pago le asigna un valor hasta que manda llamar la función `formaDePago` por lo que al recorrer las propiedades en la fila de pago no le muestra nada.

Answer (score 0):

me parece que la respuesta de @francisco-romero es bastante acertada asi que solo intentare sumar contenido a su respuesta.

Hay varios detalles que debes tomar en cuenta;

- la forma de pago es actualizada usando el metodo `formaDePago`, pero nunca lo invocas en tu codigo
- no se guarda el estado de la forma de pago elegida y por eso no lo puedes usar
- supongo que tu codigo es solo un ejemplo, pero usar `document.write` hara que se impriman todas las personas cada vez que agreges un cliente nuevo, puedes guardar el indice del ultimo cliente creado y luego usar `appendChild` o `innerHTML` para agregar a la pantalla solo la informacion del nuevo cliente
- si la forma de pago no la volveras a modificar, piensa el añadirlo como parametro al constructor de `Persona`

Puedes convertir los metodos de pago en un grupo de `radios`, ponerles el mismo id o class y usar `document.querySelector` para recuperar el radio chequeado `document.querySelector('input[id=idDeLosRadios]:checked')` (IE9+), si por alguna razon no puedes usar query selector puedes obtener los radios con `getElementById` o `getElementByClassName` y luego recorrer el resultado buscando el radio chequeado, asi te ahorras meter cs y js en la logica de tu aplicacion (en aplicaciones grandes puede causar muchos problemas y en aplicaciones pequeñas añade complejidad innecesaria)

```js
// ** Usando constructor **

function Pasajero(identificador, nombre, email, celular, edad) {
  
  this.identificador = identificador;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.email = email;
  this.celular = celular;
  this.edad = edad;
  
  }

// Variables globales

var efectivo = document.getElementById('efectivo');
var cheque = document.getElementById('cheque');
var tarjeta = document.getElementById('tarjeta');
var evento = document.getElementById('crear');
var pasajeros = []; // Cantidad de pasajeros .length
var persona = "";
var t = "";


// ** Fin Constructor **
  
// ** Prototipo del constructor **

Pasajero.prototype = {
  
  pago: "",
  
  formaDePago: function(t) {
    
    switch(t) {
        
      case 'efectivo': 
        
        return this.pago = 'efectivo';
        
        break;
       
      case 'cheque':
        
        return this.pago = 'cheque';
        
        break;
        
      case 'tarjeta':
        return this.pago = 'tarjeta';
        break;
        
      default: this.pago = 'Selecciona tu forma de pagar';
        
    }
   
}
};


// Añadimos un evento con una función anónima..
evento.addEventListener('click', function(e){
formaDePago = document.querySelector('input[id=formadePago]:checked').value;
persona = new Pasajero((pasajeros.length + 1), "aena", "aena@gmail.com", "+56958274822", "24");
persona.formaDePago(formaDePago);
pasajeros.push((pasajeros.length + 1));
// Recorremos el array
pasajeros.forEach(function(e){console.log(e);});
// Recorremos el objeto creado del constructor
for (var i in persona) {
  document.write('<hr></hr>' + i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function' ? persona[i]() : persona[i]));
}
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="array">
  <label><input type="radio" id="formadePago" value="efectivo">Efectivo</input></label>
  <label><input type="radio" id="formadePago" value="cheque">Cheque</input></label>
  <label><input type="radio" id="formadePago" value="tarjeta">Tarjeta</input></label>
  <hr></hr>
  <input type="button" id="crear" value="Crear Pasajero"/>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo cambies el campo `type="button"` por `type="checkbox"`, luego al momento de preguntar lo haces de la siguiente manera `if(efectivo.checked) { ... } else if(cheche.checked) { ... } 
...` y así sucesivamente.

Ahora si desea que solo se pueda seleccionar una forma de pago entonces utiliza `type="radio"` y colocas la propiedad `name="formaDePago"` a todas las formas de pago.

Ejemplo:

```js
// ** Usando constructor **

function Pasajero(identificador, nombre, email, celular, edad) {
  
  this.identificador = identificador;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.email = email;
  this.celular = celular;
  this.edad = edad;
  
  }

// Variables globales

var efectivo = document.getElementById('efectivo');
var cheque = document.getElementById('cheque');
var tarjeta = document.getElementById('tarjeta');
var evento = document.getElementById('crear');
var pasajeros = []; // Cantidad de pasajeros .length
var persona = "";
var t = "";


// ** Fin Constructor **
  
// ** Prototipo del constructor **

Pasajero.prototype = {
  
  pago: "",
  
  formaDePago: function() {
    
    if (efectivo.checked) {
      return this.pago = 'efectivo';
    }
    else if(cheque.checked){
       return this.pago = 'cheque';
    }
    else if(tarjeta.checked){
       return this.pago = 'tarjeta';
    }
    else {
      console.log("Selecciona método de pago por favor");
    }
    console.log(pago);
    
  }
  
};


// Añadimos un evento con una función anónima..
evento.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  persona = new Pasajero((pasajeros.length + 1), "aena", "aena@gmail.com", "+56958274822", "24" );
  pasajeros.push((pasajeros.length + 1));
// Recorremos el array
pasajeros.forEach(function(e){console.log(e);});

// Recorremos el objeto creado del constructor
for (var i in persona) {
  
  document.write('<hr></hr>' + i + ": " + (typeof persona[i] === 'function' ? persona[i]() : persona[i]));
 
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="array">
  <input type="radio" name="formaDePago" id="efectivo" value="Efectivo"/>Efectivo...
  <input type="radio" name="formaDePago" id="cheque" value="Cheque"/>Cheque...
  <input type="radio" name="formaDePago"  id="tarjeta" value="Tarjeta"/>Tarjeta...
  <hr></hr>
  <input type="button" id="crear" value="Crear Pasajero"/>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```